# How to create multiple bootstrap datetime picker while doing itereation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

Hi guys am iterating the database records in jsp using iterator. Here per each iteration text,startdatetime picker and end datetime picker. i have used date time picker with id creates a problem. I dont know how many rows i gonna iterate how can i solve this?

**In fiddle you may suggest me like this run one for loop with 5 iteration with in the first column some simple text second column start datetime picker and third column end datetime picker**

```
<s:iterator value="%{#session.subjectlist}" status="resultstatus">
<td><s:property value="#resultstatus.count" /></td>(this is serial number like 1,2,3 etc used as id in datetime picker)
<td><s:property /></td>(this is a simple text)
<td>
  <div class='input-group date' id="<s:property value="#resultstatus.count"/>">
<input type='text' name="examDate1" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" onClick="activateDatePicker()" /> 
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">/span></span>
</div>
</td>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(function() {

            $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                format : 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
                startDate : new Date(),
                autoclose : 1
            }).on('changeDate',function(selected) {

                         var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());                    
                         $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker('setStartDate',minDate); 

                        $('#adminTimeTableForm').bootstrapValidator(
                                'revalidateField', 'examDate1');
                    });

             $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker({
                format : 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
                startDate : new Date(),
                autoclose : 1
            }).on('changeDate',function(selected) {

                var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker('setEndDate', minDate);
            $('#adminTimeTableForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'examDate2');
                    });

        });   
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the error tho ? and what's the expected behavior ?

Comment: What's your expectation ? Do you need more than 1 datetimepicker on same page?

Comment: suppose i may iterate 20 rows how can enable datetime picker with id

Comment: why you don't use class ?

Comment: its not working

Comment: do you add datetimepicker runtime?

Comment: do you able to put jQuery in your loop with dynamic id? because when you put your js code in that loop then i think its working.

Comment: ya i can place dynamic id but same id am not able to send jquery function wait i ll show you

Comment: <s:property value="#resultstatus.count" /> by this code iteration count like 1,2,3 etc i placed as id of div <div class='input-group date' id="<s:property value="#resultstatus.count"/>">

Comment: this same id should match with datetimepicker7   $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({  understood now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142610/discussion-between-javedrathod-and-srinivas-gowda).